# web api 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I really cannot see what I have missed here.
This is code I am refactoring from a GET to a POST at the request of the other side of project development.

```
        using VirtualAssistant.Models;
        using VirtualAssistant.DataModel;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Configuration;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Net;
        using System.Net.Http;
        using System.Web.Http;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
        using System.Web.Http.Description;
        using System.Collections;

    namespace LloydsVirtualAssistant.Controllers
    {
        public class FetchController : ApiController
        {

            public class PersonList

            {
                public int ClientID { get; set; }
                public int PersonId { get; set; }
                public string FullName { get; set; }
                public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
                public string BusinessNumber { get; set; }
                public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
                public int LocationId { get; set; }
            public int BuidlingId { get; set; }
            public string LocationAddress { get; set; }
            public string PostCode { get; set; }
            public string BranchSortCode { get; set; }
            public string AreaName { get; set; }
        }




        // GET: ChatAi/Person/5
        [Route("FetchPerson")]

        public HttpResponseMessage POST([FromBody] PersonList PersonId)
        {
            List<PersonList> results = new List<PersonList>();
            var result = new FetchDataContext().usp_FetchPerson_GetById(PersonId).ToList();

            foreach (var item in result.ToList())
            {
                results.Add(new PersonList
                {
                    ClientID = (int)item.ClientID,
                    PersonId = (int)item.PersonId,
                    FullName = item.FullName,
                    EmailAddress = item.EmailAddress,
                    BusinessNumber = item.BusinessPhone,
                    MobileNumber = item.MobileNumber,
                    LocationId = (int)item.LocationId,
                    BuidlingId = (int)item.BuildingId,
                    LocationAddress = item.LocationAddress,
                    PostCode = item.PostCode,
                    BranchSortCode = item.BranchSortCode,
                    AreaName = item.AreaName
                });
            }
            {
                return results;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error reads

> Severity
>   Code   Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error  CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no >extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be >found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)>VirtualAssistant.....

This was originally working as a GET but the team wants a POST.  My attempt to refactor is failing.  I will of course keep searching wonder if any of you pros can spot my mistake?  It is my First Web API - well if you don't count the GET that was working.  My area of expertise is SQL, just learning ASP.NET (and loving it)

Thank you so much in advance for having a look.

Comment: I am surprised that this even compiles `usp_FetchPerson_GetById(PersonId)` seeing as `PersonId` is of type `PersonList` (see your incoming parameters).

Comment: Also chaining `new FetchDataContext` is a bad idea as you are not disposing the data context. This means that your data connections *could* remain open until the context is eventually disposed by the CLR's garbage collection which is non deterministic.

Comment: Cheers Igor, great advice. Will be sure to address this today. And no it would not compile since I altered my working GET and tried to create a POST.  But spent yesterday doing to old school reading, and an online course.  Hoping I can become a novice c# over a weekend.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving a single element here:

```
var result = new FetchDataContext().usp_FetchPerson_GetById(PersonId).ToList();
```

You can only use `ToList()` on an IEnumerable or a collection, array etc...

Try the following instead:

```
var person = new FetchDataContext().usp_FetchPerson_GetById(PersonId);
if (person != null) {
    results.Add(person);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent all day Saturday taking a step back and studying this from the beginning.  The 5 hour online course was worth it instead of deep diving in and hacking it.  

Totally an accidently API developer, my background is in SQL.  I really appreciate the feedback so I don't have to start from scratch today fixing this.  Thank you